# python raw string escaping character

Tags: python, regex, escaping

A noob question. I was reading a documentation on use of regexes in python. I was under the impression that using a raw string would treat '\' as it is and not consider whatever is following it as an escape sequence. In the example I was reading, however,

```
>>> phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\(\d\d\d\)) (\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)')
>>> mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My phone number is (415) 555-4242.')
>>> mo.group(1)
'(415)'
>>> mo.group(2)
'555-4242'
```

Clearly, the author has escaped '(' with '\' . I want to understand how. I thought putting a 'r' at the bring would treat '\' no differently.

Comment: I do not see what is unclear here. ``\`` in a raw string literal is a literal ``\``, just what we need to use to escape shorthand character classes and special regex characters with.

Comment: I think I have a big hole in my understanding of raw string. So raw string is just for the python interpreter, rest using '\' anywhere would actually do what is suppose to do, like in case of regexes?

Comment: Think of a regex engine as a customer who is delivered a string. Re requires `\d`. When you use "\d", Python thinks it is an escape sequence like `\n`, but it is not, so it retains the ``\`` since this is default behavior for unknown escape sequence and gives `\d` to the re engine. When you write `r"\d"` Python knows that ``\`` is a literal ``\`` and will readily provide `\d` to the re engine.

Comment: Okay. That makes it clear. But when we use '\\(' , regex ignores ( it because?

Comment: Use `\`` to enclose code. I do not understand what you mean. Regex never ignores `(` nor `\(`.

Comment: Can you check again. Using \ with ( ignores (. I suppose that means that using \ with anything else that regex engine do not understand simply ignores that?

Comment: The `(` is a beginning of a grouping construct and there must be a closing unescaped `)`. *These `(...)` are never part of the match*. The `\(` and `\)` are  literal `(` and `)` and these are part of the match. Is that what you needed to clarify?

Comment: I really appreciate the help Wiktor.

Comment: I collected my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` in a raw string literal is a literal `\`, just what we need to use to escape shorthand character classes and special regex characters with.

The `(` is a beginning of a grouping construct and there must be a closing unescaped `)`. **These `(...)` are never part of the match**. The `\(` and `\)` are  literal `(` and `)` and these are part of the match.

Think of a regex engine as a customer who is delivered a string. Re requires `\d`. When you use "\d", Python thinks it is an escape sequence like `\n`, but it is not, so it retains the `\` since this is default behavior for unknown escape sequence and gives `\d` to the re engine. When you write `r"\d"` Python knows that `\` is a literal `\` and will readily provide `\d` to the re engine.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this code escapes the '(' for the purposes of defining the regex, but the Python interpreter retains the '\' in the string.

Without defining this using the raw string literal form, you would have had to write:

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile('(\\(\\d\\d\\d\\)) (\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d)')
```

Comment: So, regex treat '\' as escaping a sequence?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of all those '\'s in the first place - to distinguish a '(' that the regex should interpret as a grouping operator (no escape) vs. a '(' that should be parsed in the input string (must be escaped). See how there are two groups in the given regex? The first group contains 3 digits inside parentheses. The parentheses inside the group must be escaped, else the regex compiler will think you are specifying a group within a group, and not match the parentheses in the input string.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the explanation :)